# How can I create an IAM SID from a resource name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am creating a terraform module to support a project in AWS. Most AWS resources use dashed-name-format, while SIDs only accept alphanumeric characters, and are usually CamelCaseNamed.

I have a module that accepts a list of bucket names and creates s3 buckets. I'd like to create IAM statements for those that have descriptive SIDs, but I don't want to add it as another variable that developers optionally populate.

How can I convert something like `s3-bucket-name` to a value like `S3BucketNameReadAccess`?

Comment: `"${replace("s3-bucket-name", "-", "")}ReadAccess"`. Close but not exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly the cleanest solution, but without more intrinsic functions to invoke and no possibility of custom functions, then I am unsure what other optimal solution exists:

```
locals {
  bucket_name = "s3-bucket-name"
  bucket_sid  = "${replace(title(replace(local.bucket_name, "-", " ")), " ", "")}ReadAccess"
}
```

- Inner `replace` replaces `-` characters with   single whitespace characters.
- `title` converts the first "letter" of each "word" (assuming regular expression matchers on both) to uppercase
- Outer `replace` removes   single whitespace characters (note intrinsic functions exist to remove whitespace at beginning and/or end of strings, but not within strings).
- Interpolate return value of outer `replace` with literal string `ReadAccess`.

You can confirm for yourself with an `output` that the `local.bucket_sid` is the expected value.